# java Enum or Class with few constants. which one is advantageous?

Tags: java

i have set of constants. Enum will be the best option to define set of constants.even we can define all constants in a java class. what are the advantages and disadvantages over both? i mean which one is more advantageous? Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could give a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for `enum`. Enum gives you almost the same flexibility as classes (after all, enum is a class!), so you can declare fields, methods, constructors as you will. Forget about inheritance, but hey - you should favor composition over inheritance either way ;)

Enum also gives you few cool features without any hustle:

1. it's **typesafe**
2. it's **threadsafe**
3. you could use it in `switch` and `for-loop` statements
4. you have a neat API to work with constants you define (like `valueOf(String)`)

I suggest having a look on '***Effective Java by Josh Bloch***', you will be amazed how powerful tools they really are.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply. is it possible to achieve inheritance if i use enum? Thanks!

Comment: No. You cannot inherit an enum, since it is declared as `final` class. There is really no need to do that, if you think about it, since it could add some unnecessary complexity to your code, which could break your clients. To be honest, I have never found myself in a scenario where I would need to do that as well. Stick to plain enums and you will be good :)

Comment: @Bachman:Thanks for your reply. Enum is serializable. if i declare all constants in a class, is it serializable? Please help me?

Comment: In Java you need to fulfill some conditions in order to make class serializable. This is however out of the scope of this question :)

Answer (score 3):

An enumeration of related constants is best represented as `enum`.

If the constants don't share a common trait, but are diverse, then don't use enum.

Answer (score 3):

**Enum:**

- since java 1.5
- type safe
- you can iterate through all defined values
- each constant can have more attributes - simple to write

**Static fields:**

- works in all java versions